# How to validate Jmeter result vs manual results

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jmeter

I have created **JSF** simple application and deployed **tomcat7** and tomcat port number is **7070**. The application details are:

```
1 main.jsp  
2 Login.java  
3 welcome.jsp
```

`main.jsp` page has one text field and one button `GoWelcomePage`
When we click this button action goes to `login.welcomePage()`. In this method put the sleep in 10000ms (10Secs) after that return the string value as **welcome**.
Then the page navigate into `welcome.jsp` page.

The process like
 `main.jsp-->login.goWelcomePage() {10secs or 10000ms sleep mode} -->welcome.jsp`
Obviously we know this process take more than 10secs or **10000ms**.

**I test this simple application using Jmeter. It says the process time is less than 100ms.
this is totally wrong.**
I am not sure, i have given the tight parameters into the Jmeter.
**main.jsp**

```
<h:form id="mainFormId">
    <h:inputText value="#{login.userName}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Go Welcome Page" action="#{login.goWelcomePage}"/>
</h:form>
```

**Login.java**

```
package com.jsf.demo;
public class Login {
private String userName;
{
try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    return "welcome";
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}}
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<p> Welcome </p> <h:outputText value="#{login.userName}"/>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
     <managed-bean-name>login</managed-bean-name>
     <managed-bean-class>com.jsf.demo.Login</managed-bean-class>
     <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
     <from-view-id>faces/pages/main.jsp</from-view-id>
     <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>faces/pages/welcome.jsp</to-view-id>
     </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

**Jmeter inputs**
**ThreadGroup:**
[image]
**HttpRequestDefaults:**
[image]
**HttpRequest:**
[image]
**Jmeter results**
**View Results in Table:**
[image: Results in table]
**Aggregate Report:**
[image]

My doubt is: did i gave the right inputs and getting right results in Jmeter tool?

Please help me.
Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Inputs are fine, except in **HttpRequest:** Server Name, Port & Protocol should be empty. Since you have already specified these details in **HTTP Request Defaults**

The Jmeter Sample Time (the one you have highlighted) is the **Response time**, and what you are looking for is the **Page load Time**.

Check "**Retrieve All Embedded resources from Html Files**" in **HTTP Sampler** or **HTTP Request Defaults**.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Jmeter PerfTest for your nice effort. I am looking the overall process time. means OverAllTime = from button click + goWelocmePage() + result page loading start. Is it possible to calculate the overalltime?

Comment: You can try with the above method. If this do not achieve the results you are looking for, then you need to write your own code in the BeanShell sampler for this.

Comment: This post is telling response time and sample time are equal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510846/jmeter-latency-vs-load-timesample-time. i am bit confused.

Comment: yes, but we are taking about response time & page load time