# JMeter - Response time has same value as latency

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, latency, response-time

I'm executing performance testing using JMeter and Blazemeter report, but the response time value is the same as latency time value. 
can somebody explain?
I attach the graph results:

Latency Time Graph

[image: Latency Time Graph]

Response Time Graph

[image: Response Time Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that the response is small/empty. The values are TTLB and TTFB, See [explanantion about the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510846/jmeter-latency-vs-load-timesample-time/18519692#18519692)

> Latency is a difference between time when request was sent and time when **response has started to be received**.
>
> Response time (= Sample time = Load time = Elapsed time) is a difference between time when request was sent and time when **response has been fully received**.
>
> So Response time always >= latency.
>
> The larger file is, the larger difference between response time and latency will be.

Comment: Okay noted it, so it means that latency time has relationship with the size of file too.

Comment: @RezkiOksaputri response can be empty, Not necessary a file