# Difference between Elapsed and Latency in Jmeter's JTL file

Tags: jmeter

When I run a jmeter test, I get a `.jtl` file with the following headings:

> timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect,"command"

I was wondering what the difference is between `elapsed` and `Latency`

Does anyone know?

I could not find an official reference/documentation for this headings online...if someone knows if and where they exist, please also do share!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JMeter - Response time has same value as latency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641019/jmeter-response-time-has-same-value-as-latency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

- Latency = [time to first byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte)
- Elapsed = time to last byte

Official documentation is available at [JMeter Project](https://jmeter.apache.org/) page

Kind of extension to the official documentation: [JMeter Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/Home)

Also you might be interested in [The Ultimate JMeter Resource List](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ultimate-jmeter-resource-list)

Comment: I am interested in knowing things like units the values are in. seconds? milliseconds? but cant seem to find that in the glossary

Comment: Milliseconds as of JMeter 5.3